# VS 2010 WCAG 13.1 error if link text contains the word "google"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio and Web Developer 2010, if you enable accessibility checking, you get the following error (not just a warning) when your link text contains the word "google" anywhere in it:

> WCAG 13.1 : Clearly identify the target of links.  Do not use "Click
>   Here".  Use something descriptive, like "Map of
>   campus."

Its funny, I know, but sadly true, and although it doesn't actualy prevent the compilation - it's a bit of an eyesore when there are no other errors, and quite frankly very annoying when you have to scroll for real errors. I know MS hates google ;-) but does anyone know how to make VS ignore this?

Comment: Still an issue in VS2017 v15.8.5....   :(